# Windows 8 unformatted drives data recovery

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery

My system recently crashed and I have to re-install Windows. I had 4 drives and 100GB each and system drive of 30 GB.

Now when I was installing it did not let me install on the already existing 30 GB drive.
I made a drive of 30 GB out of one of the drives.Windows installation went successful and I can't access 2 of my drives. It shows 203 Gb of unformatted data.

Is the there any way I can get the data back that was in there?

Comment: bad move, you were supposed to do troubleshooting then and there when you were not allowed to install OS on your 30Gb partition

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ontrack easy recovery](http://www.krollontrack.com/data-recovery/recovery-software/) , [EaseUS recovery wizrd tool](http://www.easeus.com/landing/data-recovery-wizard.htm?gclid=CI3x7rDj_LkCFfF54godSXEA9Q) , [Getdataback](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm)